# properly copying a thunderbird local directory

Tags: files

I back up certain directories on a nightly basis to a local NAS using rsync. Because of a recent problem I had on my machine, I decided to also make a complete copy of the local directory that contains my local files. All copies are a cron job running as root. I would like the original an backup files to have the same timestamps and ownership permissions along with everything else, so initially I used cp -rp (filename) (filename.backup). Running a diff on the two directories shows a significant number of differences. I tried to add an "L" option to follow links or a "d" option to just include the links with the same result. I even tried deleting the backup file prior to the copy with similar results. Can someone suggest a proper way to make a copy that will pass a diff test?

Thank you.

Comment: You really probably ought to look at using `rsync` instead of `cp` ...

Comment: You could `tar` files and directories and use `tar --diff`. See https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar